# Безопасно ли менять права доступа к /usr/lib/python3.6 на 777?

Tags: pip, python-3.6, sudo, chmod, chown

ОС - Убунту 16.04
python - 3.6.5
pip - 9.0.3

Ситуация следующая: при установке пакетов через pip требуется sudo.

Есть мысль, чтобы не устанавливать пакеты каждый раз от суперпользователя, изменить либо права доступа к директории **/usr/lib/python3.6** на 777, либо изменить её владельца с root на пользователя.

Безопасно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

А вы в курсе про этот ключ?

```
pip install --user
```

Comment: А директорию для установки отредактировать через **--global-option**?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы один пользуетесь пк, то более менее безопасно, единственная опасность, что сами можете удалить какой-либо файл случайно. Если есть другие пользователи, уведомите их, что лезть туда не надо. А вообще, какой смысл, 4 буквы и пробел не тратят много времени :), впрочем, вам виднее.

Comment: да меня место установки по-умолчанию (~/.local/) немного смущает. Хотелось бы кучнее всё установить.

Пользуюсь один